# How do I write a proper hide row expression?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2017

I am trying to show only those rows with the value "100".
I set the expression to

```
=IIf(("Fields!WarehouseCode.Value")=100),False,True)
```

So far I only get result "True" for the rows with 100 and false for the others. [See result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhaR6.png)
How do I hide the other rows, that don't contain the number 100?

Best,

Bogotrax

Edit: It works! Thanks alot Niktrs!
Your code worked :)

```
= ( Fields!WarehouseCode.Value <> 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the tablix row visibility to your expression

```
= ( Fields!WarehouseCode.Value<>"100")
```

**UPDATE**

changed the expression to compare string instead of integer

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello niktrs, thanks for the quick response. What do i put in the expression for the value then? I went with  =Fields!WarehouseCode.Value for the value expression and =IIf(("Fields!WarehouseCode.Value")=100),False,True) for the visibility expression. 
 I get an error when i try to upload the file "Der Visibility.Hidden-Ausdruck für das Textfeld-Objekt "txtWarehouseCode" enthält einen Fehler: [BC30516] Fehler bei der Überladungsauflösung, da keine zugreifbare "IIf" diese Anzahl von Argumenten akzeptiert."
Microsoft KB tells me that I made a  "call to an overloaded method". Is my code wrong?

Comment: For visibility use my expession and it will work